# Is there equivalent to sprintf('%+03d:00', $my_number) in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, timezone, mariadb

My goal is to convert TimeZone from number format to string (like -10 to "-10:00") in SQL (MySQL or MariaDB).

In fact I want the same as (in PHP):

```
echo sprintf('%+03d:00', $timezone);
```

```
| In  | Out      |
|-----|----------|
| -10 | "-10:00" |
| -2  | "-02:00" |
| 2   | "+02:00" |
| 10  | "+10:00" |
```

**There is a way to have it in SQL syntax ?**

I've started to write:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(timezone), CHAR), ":00");
```

But the output isn't as expected:

```
| In  | Out      |
|-----|----------|
| -10 | "-10:00" |
| -2  |  "-2:00" |
| 2   |   "2:00" |
| 10  |  "10:00" |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question has contradictions, i advice you to review and edit.. You say '"But it **don't add the sign + if needed** and **don't pad with 0 too**, examples:" but clearly you expected column values in the expected results shows those points..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for advice, let me know if it's more understandable

Comment: much more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the MySQL/MariaDB conversion with

```
  (
     CONCAT(
        CASE
          # sign condition check
          WHEN (ABS(timezone) = timezone) = 0
          THEN "-"
          ELSE "+"
         END
      , LPAD(ABS(timezone), 2, '0')
      , ":00"
     )
   ) AS alias
```

**Query with test data**

```
SELECT
   timezone AS 'In'
 , (
     CONCAT(
        CASE
          # sign condition check
          WHEN (ABS(timezone) = timezone) = 0
          THEN "-"
          ELSE "+"
         END
      , LPAD(ABS(timezone), 2, '0')
      , ":00"
     )
   ) AS 'Out'

FROM (

SELECT -10 as timezone
UNION ALL
SELECT -2 AS timezone
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS timezone
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS timezone 

) AS test_data;
```

**Results**

```
| In  | Out    |
| --- | ------ |
| -10 | -10:00 |
| -2  | -02:00 |
| 2   | +02:00 |
| 10  | +10:00 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bxTqXvKu9RYiyhkAesFLS/5)

Comment: Such dirty way, MySQL don't have much proper way to do that ? Like function `CONVERT_TZ` ?

Comment: @mouchimotte `CONVERT_TZ` is meant to convert between timezones that is you not what your question is about.

Comment: No MySQL does not have a better way.. @mouchimotte before calling it dirty..Take a look into our source data the `In` column contains a signed or unsigned `int` datatype, `time` and `datetime` datatype can't have negative values (will be converted in positive) in them so the MySQL date functions will not work.

Comment: Ho yes, but I was expecting a native function that I would have missed.

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB does not have a native C/PHP like `sprintf` function but [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) does have it native.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  dt + INTERVAL timezone HOUR;
```

Will add `timezone` hours to a `DATETIME dt`.  I assume that `timezone` is a signed integer.